# how can I select a rows that repets two atributtes

Tags: sql, select, counting

I have a table with Destino and Tronco, Fecha and I need to group the Destino and Tronco that repeats

```
SELECT Destino
    ,Tronco
    ,Count(*) AS Countrows
FROM Hist_LDS
WHERE Fecha = '2020-10-28'
GROUP BY Destino
    ,Tronco
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GMQR.jpg)

The result is empty
but if I Select without the counting this goes out

```
SELECT Destino
    ,Tronco
FROM Hist_LDS
WHERE Fecha = '2020-10-28'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKxCN.jpg)

Comment: In your first data screen capture, I actually don't see a single `(Destino, Tronco)` pair that seems to appear more than once.  Are you sure you are phrasing your question correctly?

Comment: @GMB I would actually suggest rolling back your edit.  The screen captures are also not very legible.

Comment: What RDBMS are you working on? Mysql, Sql Server, Oracle, Postgres... ?

Comment: there are 95 rows and it repeats, but i only take a pic of the first

Comment: Im working with sql server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that EITHER the Destino or Tronco repeat? What you're currently doing is looking for a repeating of the combination of the two of them - which doesn't exist in your sample data list.

If so, see if the following returns what you are after.

If not, please provide sample data including records you think should appear in you initial query.

```
--Identify duplicated Tronco values
select Tronco, Count(*) As Countrows
INTO #TRONCO
From Hist_LDS
Where Fecha='2020-10-28' 
GROUP BY Tronco
HAVING COUNT (*)>1

--Identify duplicated Destino values
select Destino, Count(*) As Countrows
INTO #DESTINO
From Hist_LDS
Where Fecha='2020-10-28' 
GROUP BY DESTINO
HAVING COUNT (*)>1


--Identify records from initial table where Destino or Tronco were repeated
select Destino, Tronco, Count(*) As Countrows
From Hist_LDS
Where Fecha='2020-10-28' 
AND (Destino in (SELECT destino from #DESTINO) OR Tronco in (SELECT tronco from #TRONCO))
```

Comment: @ArthurJ - give it a try. If it works, please mark this as the answer. If not come back with details of what went wrong.

Comment: How can I ask another thing to you